# Rails Simpleform selection is too long to fit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

**The Problem**
I am using rails version 5 and I am making a form where the user fills an input by selecting from different options. Here is what it looks like when it works:

```
<% sectors = [["Energy", "Energy"], ["Metals","Metals"], ["Agriculture","Agriculture"], ["Renewables","Renewables"]] %>
<%= f.input :sector, collection: sectors, label:"SECTOR",label_html: { style: 'font-weight:bold;margin-left:10px;' }, input_html: { class: 'f_longer' } %>
```

This works but if one of the options from the collection array is too long, it wont fit on a single line for example if "sectors" looks like this:

```
<% sectors = [["Energy", "Energy"], ["string that is too long to fit on a single line, the beginning will show but it will suddenly cut","string that is too long to fit on a single line, the beginning will show but it will suddenly cut"]] %>
```

**What I want**
Surely there's a way to customize the box that appears when you click the input but i can't find it anywhere in the simple_form
Please give me an answer that does not involve jquery if possible, as I do not use this language.

Comment: I was afraid that would be the only way... Thank you for your answer anyway @MrShemek .

Comment: I have moved my suggestion from comment to answer to make sure other people see it (and they can correct me if I am wrong).

Answer (score 0):

I think that the text is not cut by Rails or simple_form but by your browser. When I inspected the code, I saw that the whole text is visible in the page source (at the same time, it was cut when I checked possible options).

I guess that you have to use jQuery or any other JS solution.